# how to use substring instead of replace

Tags: javascript, replace

Right now I can get the string position in the div like below

```
getRange(){
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var range_clone = range.cloneRange();
range_clone.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById("test"));
range_clone.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
var start = range_clone.toString().length;
range_clone.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
var end = range_clone.toString().length;
return {
  start : start,
  end: end
};
<div id="test"><b>abc</b></div>
```

If I select abc, it will return start as 0, and end as 3

However, my question is that if I use

```
$("#test").html().substring(0, 3)
```

it will return `<b>`, but not abc in bold

How do I make it exclude the tag and only return string part?

I'm doing this because right now abc is bolded, and I want to unbold user selection using substring. I know I can do the same thing using string.replace , but string.replace only replaces the first occurrence. It doesn't allow me to replace the specific position.

How do I do this with string.substring?

Thank you for your help in advance

**UPDATE**

To make my purpose clear, I am making a text editor which allows users to unbold by selecting string.

For example, they have `<b>Please help me, I am stuck</b>`

and then they select "help me"

It should be able to insert `</b><b>` around "help me", which becomes

`<b>Please </b> help me<b>, I am stuck </b>`

so it unbolds "help me".

Comment: search for how to get the text inside html elements

Comment: Hi @dnit13
I can get it with `$("#test").text()` , but that doesn't preserve the html tags and I want to keep the html format, but only change the selected string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about text extraction in an awfully clunky way.

To grab the entire `<div>` contents in JavaScript, all you need is **[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(test.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="test"><b>abc</b></div>
```

If instead you'd like to grab the content between the `<b>` tags, you can use **[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)**, and then target the first index with `[0]`:

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var inner = test.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(inner);
```

```html
<div id="test"><b>abc</b></div>
```

Alternatively, you can do this in jQuery by combining [**.children()**](https://api.jquery.com/children/) with `.innerHTML`. Obviously, the `<b>` tag is the first child, so you'll need to use the index of `[0]` again:

```js
var inner = $("#test").children()[0].innerHTML;
console.log(inner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><b>abc</b></div>
```

#### REMOVING BOLD FONT-WEIGHT:

To remove the `bold` weighting from an element with JavaScript, you can use **[.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)**. Specifically, `.style.fontWeight = "normal"` to set the font to the default weighting. Keep in mind that you'll need to target the element itself, rather than the text (so you don't need `.innerHTML`):

```js
var inner = $("#test").children()[0];
inner.style.fontWeight = "normal";
console.log(inner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"><b>abc</b></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Actually I am making a text editor, and I want to allow user to unbold just by selecting it.

If they select the bolded string, I want to get the string position in the div, and then surround the string with </b> <b> . For example:  <b>... (some string) </b> (selected string) <b>  (some more string) </b> to unbold the selected string. 

How do I integrate your idea with this?

Comment: You don't actually want to surround the string with a `<b>` tag. Instead, you want to use the CSS property `font-weight`. Fortunately, this can be applied through JavaScript. I've updated my answer to show how this can be done :)

Comment: Hey yes this gives me an idea. I will try it out. What if the user doesn't want the whole string to be normal but just some letters in that string to be normal while keeping others bolded? Thank you again :)

Comment: You would either need to use `substring`, **or** better yet, apply a `<span>` tag that only includes the target letters. Then you could use the same principle to target the `<span>` tags(s). `<span>` tags are displayed `inline-block`, so they will preserve formatting :)

Comment: Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)

Comment: Yes I will definitely mark it after it correctly solves my problem. Thank you for reminding me :)